# If energy is supposed to be a scalar, why does this logic of solar panels work?

Tags: visible-light, solar-cells

In case of a solar panel, the light perpendicular to the surface gets absorbed while the parallel component doesn't. But wouldn't the scalar sum of magnitudes of parallel and perpendicular components of the original light be less than the magnitude of the original light? Energy is a scalar and isn't supposed to behave like that.

Comment: Don't forget that light also has momentum which is a vector quantity.

Comment: @Ruslan But aren't we talking about the energy absorbed instead of the momentum absorbed? How can the absorbed and rejected energies add up to Esinx + E cosx, when the original energy (i.e. E)  was more than that?

Comment: You need to give sources for this statement: "light perpendicular to the surface gets absorbed while the parallel component doesn't".

Comment: @stafusa https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506275/what-is-the-intuitive-way-to-understand-dot-and-cross-products-of-vectors. The accepted answer here talks about solar panels in the fourth paragraph after the picture of the sun.

Comment: @RyderRude Your interpretation of that answer is incorrect. This dependence on the dot product is not a consequence of only a single component of light being absorbed, but rather (mostly) of the panel's effective area exposed to the sunlight.

Comment: @stafusa But isn't dot product commutative? Both interpretations should work.

Comment: @RyderRude - Both interpretations don't work because your interpretation is (a) physically incorrection and (b) misses the very important concept of cross section. Consider the extreme case where the solar panel is parallel to the incoming light rays. As no light hits the panel, it produces zero energy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Energy is a scalar, but the flow of energy is not. It is a vector, and indeed for EM radiation it is the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

The Poynting vector is the flow of energy per unit time per unit area i.e. joules per square metre per second. So to get the power being absorbed by a solar cell we need to multiply the Poynting vector by the area. But the area depends on the relative directions of the panel and the light:

[image]

There isn't anything very complicated about this. If the solar panel is at an angle it intercepts less of the light and therefore absorbs less energy from the light. The power abosrbed is given by the vector dot product:

$$ P = \mathbf S \cdot \mathbf A $$

The energy flux $\mathbf S$ of the light is a vector and the area of the panel $\mathbf A$ is a vector (the [vector area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_area)) but the dot product of the two vectors gives a scalar - energy per second.